# check if cell has value if not prompt dialog with error abort script if value then run script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have searched on many forums yet and could not find this issue.

I have a script that moves a row from sheet 1 to sheet 2.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when a specific cell from sheet 1 is **forgotten** and left blank.

> When I run the `moverows()` script I want to check if this row is has any empty cells and prompt with a dialog that there are still blank cells and abort the `moverows()` script if all the cells are not blank. Then proceed without a dialog.

I hope that you can point a direction or to a thread where there is a similar question.

I don't have enough knowledge to combine the dialog prompt with a check combine it with what I've got now:

```
function Moverows5() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetID');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname1");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname 2");
  var values = sourceSheet.getRange("B8:T43").getValues();
  var range0 = sourceSheet.getRange("C8:K43");
  var range1 = sourceSheet.getRange("Q8:T43");
  var range2 = sourceSheet.getRange("P2");
  var range3 = sourceSheet.getRange("R2");
  var firstFreeRow = goToFirstRowAfterLastRowWithData(targetSheet, "A:AD"); 
  //check column to whatever column you want to check 
  targetSheet.getRange(firstFreeRow, 1, values.length, values[0].length)      .setValues(values);
  range0.clearContent();
  range1.clearContent();
  range2.clearContent();
  range3.clearContent();
  createPdf()//function gets started
} //end of first function

function goToFirstRowAfterLastRowWithData(sheet, range) {
  var v = sheet.getRange(range).getValues(),l = v.length,r;
  while (l > 0) {
    if (v[l] && v[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
      r = (l + 2);
      break;
    } else {
      l--;
    }
  }
  return r ? r : 'no data found';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check range for blanks before copying

This function checks the values array for blanks.  If blanks are found it alerts the user, identifies the blank cells and terminates the function.  Otherwise, it makes the transfer and clears some ranges.

```
function Moverows5() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sourceRange=sourceSheet.getRange("B8:T43");
  var values=sourceRange.getValues();
  var range0=sourceSheet.getRange("C8:K43");
  var range1=sourceSheet.getRange("Q8:T43");
  var range2=sourceSheet.getRange("P2");
  var range3=sourceSheet.getRange("R2");
  var firstFreeRow=targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1; 
  var noBlanks=true;
  var bA=[];
  var ro=sourceRange.getRow();
  var co=sourceRange.getColumn();
  for(var ri=0;ri<values.length;ri++) {
    for(var ci=0;ci<values[ri].length;ci++) {
      if(!values[ri][ci]) {
        noBlanks=false;
        bA.push(sourceSheet.getRange(ri+ro,ci+co).getA1Notation());
      }
    }
  }
  if(noBlanks) {
    targetSheet.getRange(firstFreeRow,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);  
    range0.clearContent();
    range1.clearContent();
    range2.clearContent();
    range3.clearContent();
    //createPdf()//function gets started
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Sorry there are blanks in the following cells: ' + bA.join(', '));
    return;
  }
}
```

If you wish you may use this function to create some test data before testing on valuable spreadsheet.

```
function createTestData() { 
  var m=1;//0 for random column positions >0 for fixed position
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();
  var cols=30;//number of columns
  var rows=50;//number of rows
  var hpref='hdr';
  var hA=[];
  var hdrA=[];
  var cA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<cols;i++) {hA.push(i+1);};
  for(var i=0;i<cols;i++) {
    if(m==0) {
      var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * hA.length);
    }else{
      var index=i;
    }  
    var hnum=hA[index];
    hdrA.push(hpref + hnum);
    cA.push(hnum);
    if(m==0) {
      hA.splice(index,1);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,hdrA.length).setValues([hdrA]);    
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,rows,cols);  
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++) {
      vA[i][j]=Number(i+1) + ',' + cA[j];
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
  sh.getRange("B8:T43").setBackground('#ff00ff');
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper that seems great, what to do if i only want to have some cells within a row to be filled out with a value or txt and some are not mandatory?(can be left blank)

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities give me an example of what you would like to do and I'll give you a solution for it.  But I think that's probably better done in another question.

Comment: Thank you Cooper after some adjustments this fase works, i've posted another question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769051/change-moverows-script-that-checks-blanks-i-a-row-to-specific-cells-left-blank-i for the remain of the code.